# The set of all equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on a uncountable set may be countable or uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, cardinals, equivalence-relations

> The set of all equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on a
>    an uncountable set may be countable or uncountable.

Can you please give examples of each. $x$~$y$:x is connected via a path. The equivalence class is entire $\mathbb R$ is an equivalence class. right? I couldn't find an example of The set of all equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on an uncountable set be uncountable. Please help me. I have found one example. I don't know, revising the question with an attempt is legal or not. sorry for an incorrect attempt.

Comment: How about the relation of equality?

Comment: You can find a countable subset $C$ within any uncountable set $S$.  You can then partition $S$ into $\{c\}$ for $c\in C$ and $S\setminus C$.  This will give you a countable partition (whence an equivalence relation with countably many equivalence classes).  The set $S$ itself can be partitioned into $\{s\}$ for $s\in S$ (i.e., the equality relation mentioned by @LordSharktheUnknown).  In fact, for any set $S$ and for any cardinality $c\leq |S|$, there exists an equivalence relation $R$ on $S$ such that $|S/R|=c$.

Comment: I will add (for people closing as "missing context") that the OP shown at least some effort. They had their own attempt in the [initial revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2567399/1), but deleted it after learning from the comments that it is incorrect. (That it is in fact not an equivalence relation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On any set you have two very simple equivalence relations (smallest and larges, if you look at ordering by inclusion).

If each element is equivalent to each other, you have single equivalence class $\{X\}$. (This corresponds to equivalence relation $R=X\times X$, i.e. $x\sim y$ for every $x,y\in X$.)

If each element is equivalent only to itself, the equivalence classes are singletons. So the partition is $\{\{x\}; x\in X\}$ and it has the same cardinality as $X$. (In the case $X=\mathbb R$ it is uncountable.) This is the relation $R=\{(x,y); x=y\}$, i.e. $x\sim y$ iff $x=y$.

If you want an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$ such that there are countably many equivalence classes, simply take any partition of $\mathbb R$ into countably many subsets and the corresponding equivalence relation. For example, you could take the partition $\mathcal P=\{[x,x+1); x\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 4):

On $\mathbb R$ if a number is equivalent only to itself, there is one equivalence class for each number $x\in R$.

If all numbers are equivalent to each other, there is one equivalence class, and one is countable.

Or say two numbers are equivalent iff they have the same floor (ie for each $x\in \mathbb R$ there is an integer $n_x$ with $n_x\le x \le n_x+1$, set $x\equiv y$ iff $n_x=n_y$). That gives a countably infinite set of equivalent classes.

---

For a different uncountable example, make two real numbers equivalent iff they differ by a rational number. That requires a little more thought, and partitions the reals as an uncountable collection of countably infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

1. On $\mathbb R$, define the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ iff $x-y \in \mathbb Z$. The set of equivalence class representative here is an uncountable set e.g. $[0,1)$.
2. On $\mathbb R - \{0\}$, define the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ iff $xy > 0$. This partitions into two equivalence classes, positive and negative reals.

Answer (score 0):

For a countable set of equivalence classes of an equivalence relation $R$ on an uncountable set $A$, how about using  $R= \{ \langle x,y\rangle| x \in A \land y \in A \}$

In other words, every element from the uncountable set stands in the $R$ relation to every element from the uncountable set.

That should give you exactly one equivalence class, namely $A$ itself, and so the set of equivalence classes in this case contains $1$ element ... making it a countable set.

Comment: I don't understand the symbol $\land$. what does it stand for? please help me.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan It's short for "and".

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan It stands for 'and'. Anyway, the point is that every elements stands in the equivalence relation to everything.

Answer (score 0):

relation $x$ ~$y$ iff $x=y$

$\{\overline{x}=\{y| y=x \}\}$ is uncountable (The singletons of R).